# User Id for securityContext.runAsUser not present in /etc/passwd

Tags: helm, kubernetes-helm, eks

I'm reviewing some containers being deployed and have found that the User ID for `securityContext.runAsUser` is not present in the container's `/etc/passwd`.

```yaml
   securityContext:
     runAsUser: 10001 # defined in container /etc/passwd
     allowPrivilegedEscalation: false
     ...
```

So, what happens when a user id is declared, but the id is not physically present in the container?

I poked around Unix/Linux and SuperUser, but my research-fu failed me. I should know this, but don't. The behavior is likely defined in *nix, but not easily uncovered.

For example:

```shell
pod: my-pod-744769cb78-4b22d
    PodSecurity Context is not set
    
    container name: my-container
    image: repos/my-container/dev/snapshot:474e45b4                                      
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false   
        privileged: <no value>  # defaults to false                             
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: <no value>       
        runAsGroup: <no value>                               
        runAsNonRoot: <no value> # if set, default, otherwise PodSecurityContext                          
        runAsUser: 10001 # defined in the container's /etc/passwd                                

    container name: envoy-sidecar
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.23.1                                      
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: <no value>   
        privileged: <no value> # defaults to false                              
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true       
        runAsGroup: 5995 # not defined                          
        runAsNonRoot: true  # if set, default, otherwise PodSecurityContext                     
        runAsUser: 5995 # not defined
```

[SecurityContext behaviors are defined here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.28/#securitycontext-v1-core)

In the above, you can see defined and undefined user IDs in the containers of the pod.

In the envoy sidecar, what happens here as the user id 5995 is not present? Who is the **effective** user in the `securityContext`?

Further [research on the Envoy container shows](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.27.0/start/docker.html#changing-the-uid-and-or-gid-of-the-envoy-user-inside-the-container) that the default user id is `101`. At this time, that something is changing the user id is not at the forefront, but that the user id is **not present** in the container's `/etc/passwd`.

```shell
% docker run -it --rm envoyproxy/envoy:v1.23.1 sh
$ cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
envoy:x:101:101::/home/envoy:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep envoy
envoy:x:101:101::/home/envoy:/usr/sbin/nologin
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep 5995
$ id 
uid=101(envoy) gid=101(envoy) groups=101(envoy)
```

Does `5995` become an effective non-privileged user and ID ignored? Does this escalate the container's privileges?